# mocha.opts reference babelhook one directory up

Tags: docker, npm, config, mocha.js

have a mocha.opts file that does

```
--require babelhook
```

It seems that the babelhook needs to be in the same directory as the node_modules directory. so

```
--myApp
  --node_modules
  --babelhook.js
  --tests
    --mocha.opts
    --mytest
```

This works fine, however, what I need ( I'll explain at the end if you care why ) is this structure

```
--node_modules
--myApp
  --babelhook.js
  --tests
    --mocha.opts
    --mytest
```

This does not work.  I get the mocha error "cannot find module babelhook"
I've tried making the mocha.opts file relative. So

```
--require ../babelhook
```

and various other attempts.  But then I just get "cannot find module ../babelhook"

If I move node_modules back down a level it works fine.  Is there anyway to do this?

The reason for this folder structure is that I have a docker container that is using a volume from my hard drive.  The docker when a docker container builds it will do the npm install then copy everything from your local path to the container ( the volume action ).  This overwrites the node_modules.  So I do npm install and then move it up a folder so the volume copy doesn't overwrite it.

Any help would be appreciated

**Edit**
Dockerfile

```
FROM node:latest

MAINTAINER reharik@gmail.com

ENV PLUGIN_HOME /home/app/current

RUN npm install mocha -g
RUN npm install babel -g

RUN mkdir -p $PLUGIN_HOME

WORKDIR $PLUGIN_HOME

ADD ./package.json $PLUGIN_HOME/package.json

RUN npm install
RUN mv node_modules ../

ADD . $PLUGIN_HOME
```

docker-compose.yml

```
plugin:
 build: .
 volumes:
  - .:/home/app/current
 command: tail -f /dev/null
 environment:
  DEBUG: true
  NODE_ENV: development
```

from package.json

```
"scripts": {
    "test": "mocha --opts ./tests/mocha.opts ./tests/unitTests/*.js"
  },
```

Comment: can you show your Dockerfile, your `docker run`  and any other info that can reproduce the problem? If you get into your container with  `docker exec -it container_id bash` can you see where is babelhook?

Comment: yes, inside of container the folder structure is as shown above ( except it's /home/app/current/ rather than just myApp ).  I'll post the Dockerfile and docker-compose above.  but I think the docker part is working as expected, it's just that the modules are one level higher than mocha expects